# Line break in string.Template()

Tags: python, python-2.7, templates, string-literals

I'm trying to automatically generate input files for a certain program. They are usually quite "long" (50-100 lines). I came across the `Template()` function, which really is perfect for my case.

```
from string import Template
temp = Template('Very long string with \
                multiple lines. \
                value = $val')
```

I need to change/define about 10 values and this can be done easily via:

```
inp = tmp.substitute(val='5')
```

Now, when I try to write "inp" to a file, there are no line breaks.
I get that it comes from the '\'. In fact I tried with '\n' before, but then the Template function yields an error ("SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal"). Do you have some suggestions how to handle this issue?

Comment: You are simply not creating your multiline string correctly.

Comment: Ok! Thanks for the link.